# LTC4380 Surge stopper MOSFET logic

Tags: mosfet, surge-protection

The LTC4380 is a surge stopper that clamps the output voltage to a predetermined value. It also limits the surge current. The MOSFET M1 needs to be selected so that it operates in safe area (SOA).
However there's an additional paragraph in datasheet which describes reverse polarity protection by using another MOSFET M2.

It seems to me that D4 would introduce a voltage drop on gate voltage of M2. So during clamping process, the limiting MOSFET would then be M2 not M1?
At the same time it seems M2 would be reacting slower due to R4 being 1 Mohms (very high).

So how would the MOSFET-s act during surge? Which MOSFET will drop the surge voltage?

[image]

Comment: M2 would be unable to stop the surge due to its body diode anyways. (Unlikely that that will survive a surge either unless the FET is conducting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The LTC4380 is a surge stopper that clamps the output voltage to a
> predetermined value*

The output voltage is not technically clamped; the output voltage is "limited" or, maintained surge-free by linear regulation using M1 as the main series regulating element. "Clamp" is not a great term to use because it implies shunt regulation (like a zener diode).

> *So during clamping process, the limiting MOSFET would then be M2 not
> M1?*

When the input supply is reversed there can be no clamping process or regulation process; the output is prevented from going negative by M2 "blocking" negative voltage at the input from reaching the output.

> *So how would the MOSFET-s act during surge? Which MOSFET will drop the
> surge voltage?*

- If the input voltage is negative (undesired) M2 blocks
- If the input voltage is positive (desired) M1 regulates during a surge

Comment: Thanks Andy. Is that your opinion that during a surge the M2 will be completely saturated and conducting via its N channel rather than body diode? I still cant get around the fact that  due to D4 the Vgs is smaller on M2 than on M1.

Comment: During a positive surge it doesn't matter whether M2 is conducting through its channel or not because M1 does the regulating and, it is in series with M2. With 12 volts in (and no surge) both M1 and M2 will have enough gate-source voltage to ensure they are thoroughly activated into their [triode region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqd1N.gif). The 0.7 volts lost due to D4 is inconsequential.

Comment: I would disagree here. Since they are in series, they have same current in them. The power dissipation and SOA calculations is based on the voltage drop. If M2 is not properly conducting, the SOA needs to be calculated accordingly. I quess my quest is, can I use smaller, less capable mosfet as M2 and more powerdul as M1.

Comment: If M2 is not properly conducting in the conventional MOSFET way, its body diode comes to the rescue. Hence M2's power dissipation is very low compared to M1 during a positive surge. In your mind's eye just replace M2 with a diode (anode to incoming supply and cathode to M1 source).

Comment: [M2's body diode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMMCC.png) <-- this should demonstrate how the body diode in M2 comes to the rescue.